# xCode iOS static library cross-referenced project - all sublassed or extended UI object methods fail at runtime

Tags: iphone, static, subclass

I had completed an iPhone, and then decided to build an iPad version.  So, upgrading to xCode 4, I decided to create a workspace with 3 projects - iPhone, iPad, and Common (cross-refernced static library).  I then stripped all of the classes I was using in the iPhone project that I felt could be used in the iPad as well.  I placed those "common" classes in my static library project.

My next step was to build and make sure my iPhone project still worked.  After running the app, several of the methods that I'm calling that are now in the static library are failing - causing the app to crash, SIGBRT, etc.

Upon further investigation, I determined that all the methods that are failing or causing the crash are coming from either UI subclassed objects, or from UI extended objects.  For example, one of my classes extends UITableView with a custom method.  This causes a crash.  Another method is from a custom subclass that inherits from UILabel.  This also causes a crash.

All other objects/methods in the static library seem to be working fine.  Does anyone have an idea what's happening here?  Do I need some extra build configuration setup in my project to get this to work?  I can't imagine I'm not allowed to use UI subclassing/extensions in my static library, but who knows...

Any help/insight would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to see you have managed to get this working. I am looking to do something similar with workspaces. I want to have a workspace with a Mac and iPad project and have a library project that is used for data access that is used by both projects. Now you have got this up and running do you see any issues with what I am trying to achieve ie is it possible to have multiple projects in a workspace that require their own build as I know the workspace has a single build directory for all its projects. Would be interesting to know from somebody who has done it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set -all_load in Linking in your Build Settings.

Comment: Ok - I was wrong this did work.  However, I should clarify.  The reason it didn't work for me before, was because I set the -all_load switch in the static library project.  The -all_load switch needs to be set in the primary project instead, the one that uses the static library.  Thanks!